# flutter (ui design) my text field adjust badly to its parent container

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive-design, flutter-layout, ui-design

Hi im trying to make a responsive ui, so I adjust my width & height thoroughly with mediaquery.of(context).size. Now, the problem I've been currently dealing with is that my textfield does not exactly adjust wisely with its parent container leaving the text raised.

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginUI {
  LoginUI(this.myClipper, this.myBGClipperColor, this.myColorLightOrange);

  final Color myColorLightOrange;
  final Color myBGClipperColor;
  final CustomClipper myClipper;

  Widget getLoginUIWidget() {
    return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      Size mediaSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      return Container(
        width: mediaSize.width,
        height: mediaSize.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipPath(
              child: Container(
                color: myBGClipperColor,
              ),
              clipper: myClipper,
            ),
            Text("\n   Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Container(
              width: mediaSize.width * .8,
              height: mediaSize.height * .8,
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  mediaSize.width * .1,
                  mediaSize.height * .23,
                  mediaSize.width * .1,
                  mediaSize.height * .1),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: mediaSize.height * .25,
                      width: mediaSize.width * .8,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/image_pushing_cart.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )),
                  **Container(
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints(maxHeight: mediaSize.height * .070),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.45),
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 4,
                              offset: Offset(3.5, 4))
                        ]),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          hintText: "Email",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.teal,
                            ),
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: myColorLightOrange),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),**
                  Text("\n"),
                  **Container(
                      constraints:
                          BoxConstraints(maxHeight: mediaSize.height * .070),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.45),
                                spreadRadius: 1,
                                blurRadius: 4,
                                offset: Offset(3.5, 4))
                          ]),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.enhanced_encryption,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                            hintText: "********",
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: myColorLightOrange),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ))**
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Here is an image example

[image]

Is there a possibility that textfield would adjust accordingly whichever I gave its parent's (Container) width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line.

```
textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply the padding to the content of the TextField. You can apply this code `contentPadding property ,TextAlign property` and also add
`isDense` can be use for precise padding

```
new TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(isDense: true,,hintText: "Email", contentPadding: 
           const EdgeInsets.all(20.0))
          )
```